# Can we use CoordinatorLayout and TabLayout in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using this Siliding menu https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1398

On Home Page it load Fragment.

And i Want to design Home screen as http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/collapsing-toolbar-with-tabs-android-example/.

So, my question is

**can we use coordinator layout and TabLayout(Which will have again three fragment) in Fragment?**

if not what is other solution?

Comment: You can use a CoordinatorLayout and a TabLayout. What is stopping you, or what problem have you had implementing it? More importantly, what purpose does the CoordinatorLayout provide for you?

Comment: @cricket_007 I use it for Collapsing Toolbar With Tabs and Navigation Menu which i am using thats Load Fragment as Home page. In home page i want to use Collapsing Toolbar With Tabs and View Pager. So can we achieve this using fragment?

Comment: Sure, you can, but that doesn't mean it's the best approach. You should try to implement first before asking your question.